# Uninitialized constant Builder (NameError) - Ruby

Tags: ruby, builder, nameerror

I need to use XmlMarkup. 
In my script, I import "builder" but when I create an element I receive the error "uninitialized constant Builder (NameError)". Here the step that fails:

```
require 'rubygems/builder'
...
xml = Builder::XmlMarkup.new( :indent => 2)    ===>  uninitialized constant Builder (NameError)
```

I tried also using other syntax, like:

```
::Builder::XmlMarkup.new( :indent => 4 )
```

but I received the same error

Answer (score 4):

Write as below, as [`Usage`](https://github.com/jimweirich/builder#usage) is telling :

```
require "builder" # when your ruby version is 1.9 or greater.
```

Comment: `require 'rubygems'` should not be necessary

Comment: @p11y I mentioned as documentation is saying.. :-) I know 1.9 <= Ruby version no need it..

Comment: I tried it and I have this error message "undefined method 'require_gem' for main:Object (NoMethodError)"

Comment: If I just put "require "builder"" I have the error "C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require':
cannot load such file -- builder (LoadError)". To make it run I should write "require 'rubygems/builder"

Comment: Using "require "builder"" I have the problem posted ("uninitialized constant Builder (NameError)") in the line xml = Builder::XmlMarkup.new( :indent => 2)

Comment: Did you `gem install builder`?

Comment: @ArupRakshit I just mean to say that it is not required with recent versions of Ruby :)

Comment: @p11y I got your point.. No objection from me... :-) I will install it in my laptop today, this gem. And I will try to verify OP's problem. Why is getting error..

Answer (score 1):

Uninitialized name error means you spelled the class wrong. XmlMarkup is case sensitive

Answer (score 0):

In my case i had to do:

```
require "builder/xmlmarkup"
```